# Concat if first is empty

Tags: rx-java2

I need to fill in a list in my app with Events.

I can request Events by type A, then if the result is not empty I fill in that list.

If the result is empty, I need to retrieve by type B, and fill the list with it.

I thought about concating two RxJava Singles, but doing it only if the first is empty. I see the logic in my mind but I cannot put it to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you meant sources with type `Single<List<T>>` since an empty `Single` is not possible. In this case, use `flatMap`:

```
eventSourceA
.flatMap(list -> {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return eventSourceB;
    }
    return Single.just(list);
})
.subscribe(list -> { /* ... */ });
```